# How to find the longest consecutive non-zero subset of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, subset

I have a list of floats that somewhat looks like this:

```py
[
 163.33333333333334,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 154.73684210526315,
 172.94117647058823,
 155.8303886925795,
 0.0,
 156.93950177935943,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 151.5463917525773,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 165.1685393258427,
 156.93950177935943,
 169.6153846153846,
 159.7826086956522,
 167.04545454545453,
 158.06451612903226,
 168.9655172413793,
 157.5,
 0.0,
 159.7826086956522,
 0.0,
 163.94052044609666,
 166.41509433962264,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
]
```

The actual list is much larger than this but has similar values.
From this list, I want to find the largest consecutive subset of this that is nonzero. In this case that would be:

```py
 [165.1685393258427,
 156.93950177935943,
 169.6153846153846,
 159.7826086956522,
 167.04545454545453,
 158.06451612903226,
 168.9655172413793]
```

I am new to python and python and coding in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forget Python and coding for a while -- think *carefully* about how you might do this by hand. You would scan down the list, keeping track of certain things. Once you understand how you would do it without Python, translate your algorithm to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), grouping on whether the values are 0 or not, then select all sublists which have non-zero values and find the one with the maximum length:

```py
from itertools import groupby

g = groupby(l, key=lambda x:x>0.0)
m = max([list(s) for v, s in g if v > 0.0], key=len)
print(m)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
[
 165.1685393258427,
 156.93950177935943,
 169.6153846153846,
 159.7826086956522,
 167.04545454545453,
 158.06451612903226,
 168.9655172413793,
 157.5
]
```

Note that since you only need to compare with `0`, you can just use `bool` as the `groupby` function (i.e. `g = groupby(l, bool)`). This should be faster than comparing with `0`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple algorythm with buffer

make a for loop, then get current subset, then if length of current subset is more than maximum, set is as maximum.

```
def get_longest_consecutive_non_zero_subset(input_list: list) -> list:

    max_subset = []
    current_max_subset = []

    for number in input_list:
        if number > 0:
            current_max_subset.append(number)
        else:
            if len(current_max_subset) > len(max_subset):
                max_subset = current_max_subset
            current_max_subset = []

    return max_subset


test_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
result = get_longest_consecutive_non_zero_subset(test_list)

print(result)
assert result == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the way how [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) works with unsorted data:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [163.33333333333334, 0.0, 0.0, 154.73684210526315, 172.94117647058823, 155.8303886925795, 0.0, 156.93950177935943, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 151.5463917525773, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 165.1685393258427, 156.93950177935943, 169.6153846153846, 159.7826086956522, 167.04545454545453, 158.06451612903226, 168.9655172413793, 157.5, 0.0, 159.7826086956522, 0.0, 163.94052044609666, 166.41509433962264, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
result = max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, bool) if k), key=len)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_non_zero_subset(arr):    
    max_non_zero = []    
    curr_non_zero = []    
    for n in arr:    
        if n == 0:    
            if len(curr_non_zero) > len(max_non_zero):    
                max_non_zero = curr_non_zero    
            curr_non_zero = []    
        else:                                                                           
            curr_non_zero.append(n)    
                                                                                    
    return max_non_zero if len(max_non_zero) >= len(curr_non_zero) else curr_non_zero
```

Comment: I want the list itself, not the length

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some if statement. Hence you say you're new to python, I preferred to keep the code as easy as possible, but it would be a nice "training" to optimize it

```
fulllist = [163.33333333333334, 0.0, 0.0, 154.73684210526315, 172.94117647058823, 155.8303886925795, 0.0, 156.93950177935943, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 151.5463917525773, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 165.1685393258427, 156.93950177935943, 169.6153846153846, 159.7826086956522, 167.04545454545453, 158.06451612903226, 168.9655172413793, 157.5, 0.0, 159.7826086956522, 0.0, 163.94052044609666, 166.41509433962264, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,]

longest = []
new_try = []

for element in fulllist:
    if element != 0:
        new_try.append(element)

    if new_try>longest:
        longest = new_try.copy()

    if element == 0:
        new_try = []

print(longest)
```

Output:

```
[165.1685393258427, 156.93950177935943, 169.6153846153846, 159.7826086956522, 167.04545454545453, 158.06451612903226, 168.9655172413793, 157.5]
```